# Strange characters shown online for region specific languages post web 8 upgrade

Tags: dxa, web8, encoding

We have number of regional language sites. Post upgrading our sites we are getting an issue with language specific characters, especially the '**č**' character. when we preview the page the content looks fine '**trečią kartą laimėjo** '. But online the character gets replaced by question marks and looks something like :
**tre�?ią kartą laimėjo**

Please advice what could be wrong. I am not sure where to start looking.

Comment: check this http://elenaserghie.blogspot.in/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html

Comment: The blog post mentioned by Raj is probabaly not so useful for Web 8, since the problem is most likely in the Content Delivery services and their configuration is not described in there. DXA can handle UTF-8 encoded content, so most likely one of the microservices or your deployer is not correctly encoding the content to UTF-8 somewhere along the publish/deploy path.

Comment: That is correct Bart. It was an encoding issue indeed.We had  missed to configure UTF8  in our deployer during upgrade which caused this issue.

Comment: Hi @User_2016. Can you add your fix as an answer to this question (rather than a comment), please? That will help others with a similar problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @User_2016. Can you add your fix as an answer to this question please? That will help others with a similar problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As from comment:

> It was an encoding issue indeed. We had missed to configure UTF8 in our deployer during upgrade which caused this issue.